# show by calculation that the derivative of the fermi function (logistic function) can be expressed by the function itself

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

I'm taking a course on Neural Networks.

one of the questions on our exam will (*likely*) be:

`Show by calculation that the derivative of the Fermi function (logistic function) can be expressed by the function itself.`

Accordingly I've consulted with my friend, he proposed me this as a solution:

**Step 1**

$ f(x) = 1/(1+e^{-x}) $

→

$ f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} (1 + e^{-x})^{-1}$

To interject here, the $\frac{d}{dx}$  term is basically meaningless- it just indicates that we're taking a derivative- isn't it?

---

**Step 2**

$ f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}  (1 + e^{-x})^{-1}=$

$ = -1  ( (1 + e^{-x})^{-2} )  ( (0 + e^{-x}) (-1) )=$

---

**Step 3**

$= -1  ( (1 + e^{-x})^{-2} )  ( (0 + e^{-x}) (-1) )=$

$ = e^{-x} / (1 + e^{-x})^2 =$

---

**Step 4**

$ = e^{-x} / (1 + e^{-x})^2 =$

$ = (1+ e^{-x} -1) / (1 + e^{-x})^2 =$

---

**Step 5**

$ = (1+ e^{-x} -1) / (1 + e^{-x})^2 =$

$ = ( 1 / ( 1 + e^{-x} ) ) - ( 1 / (1 + e^{-x})^2 )= $

---

**Step 6**

$ = ( 1 / ( 1 + e^{-x} ) ) - ( 1 / (1 + e^{-x})^2 ) =$

$ = f(x) - ( f(x) )^2 =$

---

**Step 7**

$ = f(x) - ( f(x) )^2 =$

$= f(x)  ( 1 - f(x) )$

---

So essentially what I would like to know is: *is that correct?*

But also- I would like to know how we arrived to that solution, is it possible that someone could explain this to me in English as if I were a 5 years old child?

Comment: Step 1: The $\frac{d}{dx}$ is needed if you write $f'(x)$ on the LHS.

Comment: righto- that's what I thought. thank you.

Comment: I started going through your steps, but honestly it was confusing since it wasn't formatted using MathJax. If you want people to look at your problem properly (especially when it is long), you should use MathJax (LaTeX, basically). You can find a guide here: meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference